# Cannot run psql in PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql, ssl, psql, postgresql-9.5

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I receive the below error when I type `psql`:

```
 psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

On checking the logs in `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log`, I see the error as:

> 2018-11-26 13:17:41 IST [3508-1] FATAL:  could not access private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key": Permission denied

Below are the permissions of the `/etc/ssl/private` and `ssl-cert-snakeoil.key` files:

```
vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E480:~$ ls -l /etc/ssl
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     20480 Nov 22 13:06 certs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     10835 Dec  8  2017 openssl.cnf
drwxr--r-- 2 root ssl-cert  4096 Nov 22 13:06 private

vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E480:~$ sudo ls -l /etc/ssl/private
total 4
-rw-r----- 1 root ssl-cert 1704 Nov 22 13:06 ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

The `postgres` user is also added to the group `ssl-cert`.

```
vivek@vivek-ThinkPad-E480:~$ getent group ssl-cert
ssl-cert:x:112:postgres
```

**NOTE:** I found that there is no `server.key` present in `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main`.

I also posted this on [DBA Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223413/cannot-run-psql-in-postgresql-9-5), but no response as yet.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction in setting permissions?

Comment: Are you sure the server is running? For a local connection, it probably does not even need SSL.

Comment: @Thilo I get `active` status when I run `sudo service postgresql status` as shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/TBhAQPy). Strange part is, I don't see any service running on port `5432` when I do `sudo netstat -lntp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can never work, and your server will not be able to start, because the OS user `postgres` has no permissions to access files in `etc/ssl/private`.

To allow users in the group `ssl-cert` to access files in the directory, run

```
chmod g+x /etc/ssl/private
```

While you're at it, make sure that `/etc/ssl` has the required permissions.

To test if everything works, become user `postgres` and try to read the file.

Comment: That's working now. What does `g+x` exactly do? I had added `postgres` to the group `ssl-cert`  and I also noticed that the log was getting created when I did `sudo service postgresql restart`. So, that means the server was never getting restarted(not sure if it even started in the first place). It's strange that it didn't report anything on the terminal.

Comment: Ahh, my bad! It had to be `5`, i.e, `r-x` for the group `ssl-cert ` and `0`,i.e, `---` for others.  Thanks again.